# How to navigate from an embedded collection view’s cell to another view controller without using Storyboard or IB?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

About the app (UICollectionView within UICollectionView):

- TabBarController is the app window’s root view controller
- TabBarController contains 3 Navigation Controllers.
- 1st Navigation Controller has `HomeViewController` as root view controller
- `HomeViewController` contains `CategoryCollectionView`
- Inside each cell of `CategoryCollectionView` is present one `ItemCollectionView`
- Each `ItemCollectionView` contains many `ItemCell`

*Objective*: When user clicks on an `ItemCell`, the app should navigate to a different view controller, the ItemViewController. I’m developing this app completely using code. So I want to do this without Storyboard segues or IB. I haven’t been able to figure it out so far. If you could point me in the right direction, it would be great. Thanks.

I tried the following, but they didn’t work:

*First method*: Accessing the window’s root view controller from within the `CategoryCollectionView`’s cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let currentNavCon = self.window?.rootViewController!.navigationController
    currentNavCon?.pushViewController(ItemViewController(), animated: true)
}
```

*Second method*: I defined a function `itemCellClicked` in `HomeViewController`, and called it from within `didSelectItemAt` of `CategoryCollectionView`’s cell.

```
func itemCellClicked(_ sender: CatalogViewCategoryCell, _ position: Int) {
    let itemViewController = ItemViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(itemViewController, animated: true)
}
```

And, inside the cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    HomeViewController().itemCellClicked(self, indexPath.item)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pushing view controller from cell is never a good idea. You need to propagate your click event from `ItemCell` to all the way to `HomeViewControlller`.
In your `CategoryCollectionView` define a public property of type closure.

```
var onDidSelectItem: ((IndexPath) -> ())?
```

Now in `CategoryCollectionView`'s `didSelectItem`, call the closure like this.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.onDidSelectItem?(indexPath)
}
```

In your `HomeViewControlller`'s `cellForRow`, receive the callback.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    categoryCollectionView.onDidSelectItem = {(indexPath) in
       //item at indexPath clicked, do whatever you want to do with it.
    }
}
```

Comment: When there's only one Collection View, I got this figured out. When we have another collection view embedded inside the first collection view's cell, as is my case, how does this work?

Comment: Follow the same course of action, define a closure like `onDidSelectItem` inside your inner most collection view cell, now in `didSelectItemAt` call this closure. And in the outer collection view, follow the code I have already provided you in the answer.

Comment: Let me know if you're still confused, I will update the answer with some more code.